# Passing a php array into javascript using JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a multidimensional array, here:

```
$noticeDate = json_encode( $noticesDates );
```

and I want to pass the array into javascript:

var unavailableDates[] = $noticeDate;

Both variables are in the same php file so there is little point using $.getJSON, which basically looks for the variable in an external file. However, how do I pass the object into the javascript array in the same script.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant directly assign php variables to js, but you can use something like that:

```
<script>
  var unavailableDates = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($noticeDates) ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: @Christoph's solution lacks the client-side JSON parsing that is included here. This is the more complete solution.

Comment: var unavailableDates = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($noticesDates) ?>');
    document.write(unavailableDates); doesnt seem to print it out

Comment: Why do you want to print it out? It's an object you can't just simply print it. If that's your goal you should use a different format imho.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var array = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($noticesDates) ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
[$.pareseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

here is example:

```
var json = "<?php echo json_encode($noticesDates); ?>";

jsArray = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: How does this even attempt to answer the question? Please change your answer to something more resembling one.