# Setting php variable through javascript

Tags: php

I want to update some javascript variables by sending some php values through POST. Can we join both of them? My website is http://www.nattyshirts.com and i am trying to make some interactive online modules.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925287/passing-a-php-array-into-javascript-using-json. In general, converting it to Json would be your best bett translating from server side code to something that can be used in Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign Php variable value to Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895842/how-to-assign-php-variable-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: i thing he made wrong titile. should be `setting up javascript variable through php` as he describe in his question content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ajax to communicate between client and server. [Here are some examples](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=using%20ajax%20to%20send%20javascript%20variables&oq=using%20ajax%20to%20send%20javascript%20variables&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.8300j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=using%20ajax%20with%20php)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$your_post_value = $_POST['your_post_var']; // get post value in your php variable

?>

<script>
var your_js_var = '<?php echo $your_post_value;?>'; // set up your js variable by php variable
</script>
```